# Ng-if doesn't work when contained in a String. How can I get it to work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if, angularjs-ng-if

I have declared a variable called `authenticated` that I want to use to show or hide a button in a popover. The user should only see the button if he has already authenticated.

I tried the `ng-if` with the variable in the **h5** part and here it works. I think it is just the formatting inside the string for **data-content** because when I inspect the page it doesn't use the `ng-if` but it shows it in the source code.

```
<span ng-switch-when="null"
    class="redbox label label-primary {{types[charge.Type].CSS}}"
    style="cursor:pointer;"
    onclick="$(this).popover('toggle')"
    data-html='true'
    data-toggle="popover"
    data-trigger="manual"
    data-placement="top"
    title="{{&quot;common.BatchStatus-NotPaired&quot;|i18n}}"
    data-content="{{ getPopoverTemplate(charge) }}
        <a href='#/delete-batch?id={{charge._id}}' class='btn btn-primary btn-block' ng-if='authenticated'><span>{{&quot;common.Delete-Batch&quot;|i18n}}</span></a>">
  <h5 ng-if='authenticated'><strong>{{charge.LogicalId}} ({{charge.RfidNullCounter}})</strong></h5>
</span>
```

Comment: Just to make it clear. It works on the `<h5>` element but does not work in the `<a>` element? And just a side note which might affect the situation is that you're not correctly closing the `<span>` tag. You have the `<a>` element inside the `<span>` tag and you close the span after it. This is not proper HTML structure.

Comment: @thepio Yes it works on the '<h5>' element but not in the '<a>' element. How could the '<a>' element be insiede the '<span>' tag if I close it before? I don't know if I understand you correct here.

Comment: @IAmRoot have you tried correcting the HTML?

Comment: @thepio see my edit of the comment. I don' know exactly what you mean or what/how to correct it.

Comment: Yeah sorry for confusing the stucture. I removed my answer. But are you using a plugin for the popover or what happens on the click event? Can you share some code.

Comment: As I said already I am new to the topic and I am just working on a project that already exists. I think the popover is just the "standard" html/angular popover.  When you click the button it will load another page with a parameter, like you see here: `...href='#/delete-batch?id={{charge._id}}'...`  There I can delete a batch. Thats why there is the authentication and why the button should only show if you have the rights to delete something.

Comment: I think, that `ng-if` in h2 are compiling by angularjs, but text inside `data-content` - not. You are mixing the angular way and jquery way.

Comment: @AlexanderAnikeev ok. But how can I make it work? Do you know a way to show the button/link in the popover and show/hide it with ng-if? I also tried it with a template in the controller, see here: `data-content="{{ getPopoverTemplate(charge) }}`